# SharePoint 2013 Convert Column Type to Lookup

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have imported an excel sheet to al list which had some lookup values.
But now when I look at the list the lookup column is now single line of text.
How can I change the column to reconnect back to the list for a lookup.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

**Lookup Fails after Import**
Cause:-Table Key was invalid (I suspect)

I exported access tables as "Share point list" and some of the lookups no longer
 work. To fix I had to delete and recreate the list.

*To Fix:*  Delete the table with the lookup in, and then recreate it. This fixes the error.

*Did not work:*

- rename the column to "Lookup old" and recreate.
- delete the column with the look up are recreate.

I was also getting this error: 
"Cannot save property; property is a schema property".
Re-creating the table also fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

The work around is :

-Create the list  with required fields.

-Import all the other columns

-Open the list in Sharepoint, Edit in Datasheet

-Select records in "Lookup" column in Excel (not the column, only the records in the column)

-Paste in the Datasheet ensuring that sorting and positioning match.

[Reference1](http://importexceldatatosplist.codeplex.com/workitem/5982) 
[Reference2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a17709f8-00d5-4d69-a733-b4b958ae92e9/export-to-excel-breaking-wiht-lookup-field?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)

Comment: Thanks.But what do you mean by "Change the required fields to off where applicable" Please elaborate more
I have imported the column into the list already with values like so ABC;#15,BBB#3
Just thinking how I can match it and if not move it to another column

Comment: create a list with the required fields and import all other columns

Comment: So are you saying not to import from excel sheet but create a list first with all the required field and then what?
Let me elaborate.I have a lookup list already in place and when i did the export from excel the lookup column is a single line of text and i can't turn it to a lookup menu.
The single line of text are in the format Open;#1
Close ;#15. Since i exported it from a lookup column list.
Do you get me?

Comment: In a column field I have "Open;#1" and I would like set this as a lookup column .But a look up columns needs this format "1;#Open".Is there a way around this. I also would need a multivalued one like so  "Open;#1;# International;#2;#International1".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to

1. delete the old column and
2. add the new column with same name and mark it as lookup

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this Problem follow these steps: (After Import Excel Sheet in the SharePoint list)

1. From Ribbon list open the file by using InfoPath.
2. From ribbon create Data Source to the list that you want the column lookup.
3. Go to the control that you need to make it look up and Chang binding to the list that you created in Data Source and choose your Column.
4. Save And Publish.
5. Go to the SharePoint List and add new item for test.